# Assume F is a σ-fields in Ω , show (S3) holds for A : = {F ⊆ Ω : f-1 (F) ∈ F }

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here, I found a lemma which was quite close to it, but was still confused how to prove.

Here is the lemma:
[image]